PhpSpreadsheet > Xls > Remove empty rows
I'm dealing with file 10k rows+ and I wan't to delete some of rows.
Using method removeRow from ReaderXls taking to much time and kills execution of script, so I decided to empty those rows, celby cell and I'ts very fast but now I have file with empty rows.
Is ther fast way to save such file without those empty rows ? I've searched lot of resource bu could not find any good way
